# Sending multitple emails in an array

Tags: email, laravel, email-validation

Hello I want to send some emails in my application but there is one thing I am worried about, if I have 5 emails in an array, 4 valid and 1 invalid, when the email function is executed what happens? Do the 4 valid emails get sent? Or do none of them get sent at all? And if so how would I go about returning the invalid email to the user.

example of an invalid email in this case:

> scoobydoobydoo@yaho,com

I would like to get all invalid emails and display them to the user after sending the valid ones.

Comment: You must validate the email input first before sending the email. If validation failed you can output the error to the user. Laravel already have email validation. See here
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation

$validator = Validator::make(
    [
        'email' => 'email@example.com'
    ],
    [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]
);

Comment: I know this, my question is i am sending emails in an array, if 4 of them are valid and 1 is invalid what happens? Do the 4 get sent or do none of them get sent at all?

Comment: You get a exception from Swift Mailer. Swift_RfcComplianceException
Address in mailbox given ['scoobydoobydoo@yaho,com']   
does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. I don't know if some emails are already sent. Test it!

Answer (score 0):

The user will not be able to get an immediate response.  This would be a job for a Queue.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues

You'll need to run these processes in the background and then monitor for failed addresses to be picked up, where you can then notify or alert the user in whatever manner you wish.